# How to optimize mysql distinct query

Tags: mysql

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT metadata.dimension_value FROM metadata WHERE metadata.name = 'content' AND metadata.dimension_name = 'lang'
```

takes around 20 seconds to execute.

Showing the creation of the table gives this:

```
CREATE TABLE `metadata` (
  `metadata_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `resource_id` int NOT NULL,
  `dimension_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dimension_value` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` longtext,
  `content` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`metadata_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `INDEX_UNIQUE_METADATA` (`resource_id`,`name`,`dimension_name`,`dimension_value`),
  KEY `INDEX_FK_RESOURCE` (`resource_id`),
  KEY `INDEX_NAME` (`name`),
  KEY `INDEX_METAKEY` (`resource_id`,`dimension_name`,`dimension_value`,`name`),
  KEY `INDEX_DIMENSION_NAME` (`dimension_name`),
  KEY `INDEX_DIMENSION_VALUE` (`dimension_value`),
  KEY `INDEX_VALUE` (`value`(255)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `INDEX_CONTENT` (`content`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_RESOURCE` FOREIGN KEY (`resource_id`) REFERENCES `resource` (`resource_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

A count on that table gives: 6 902 215 rows

To me it sounds strange that it should take up to 20 seconds to run the query.
What could the problem be?
My learning about indexing is that fields that appear in WHERE/ORDER/GROUP should be indexed.
And both "dimension_name" and "name" are indexed.
What other could be wrong? Running a DESC for the query gives this:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: metadata
partitions: null
type: ref
possible_keys: INDEX_UNIQUE_METADATA,INDEX_NAME,INDEX_METAKEY,INDEX_DIMENSION_NAME,INDEX_DIMENSION_VALUE
key: INDEX_NAME
key_len: 202
ref: const
rows: 887774
filtered: 50.00
Extra: Using where; Using temporary
```

Comment: Try an index on `(name, dimension_name, dimension_value)` or possibly just the first two columns. The covering index will be faster but you already have quite a few indices. Are they all being used?

Answer (score 1):

Whether a query will result in using an index or not depends on the fact that after using an index, how many records would it still have to go through.
E.g. in your query, there is a criteria `metadata.name = 'content'`.
Now, if most of the records have the value of `name` set to 'content', then there is no point in using that index, as sequential access to all the rows will be faster rather than using an index and then going through most of the records.

This is called cardinality.  Low cardinality means there are not many distinct values.  So, for ONE value, there are too many records.

High cardinality means there are very different values for a column. I.e. for a single value of a column, it narrows down to very few records.

The chances of using an index are high when there is high cardinality.

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM metadata;
```

This will show the cardinality of each index that you have on the table.

Refer:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html